# Use a clicked class to find ID of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got several boxes with class="big_square"
They all have ID's which are dynamically generated by some Java call to an Oracle DB
Based on which is clicked, I would like to get the specific element ID and return it as a variable for the next call

Here is the HTML:

```
<DIV style="DISPLAY: block" id=big_square_container>
<DIV id="2" class=big_square></DIV>
<DIV id="3" class=big_square></DIV>
<DIV id="4" class=big_square></DIV>
<DIV id="5" class=big_square></DIV>
<DIV id="6" class=big_square></DIV></DIV>
</DIV>
```

and the jquery with which I am trying to find the ID:

```
$(".big_square").click(function(){
    $(".big_square").animate({opacity: .4}, 'fast', 'linear', function() {
      }); 
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 'fast', 'linear', function() {
      }); 
   var x = $(this).getElementbyID();
    console.log(x);
    response.setAttribute("x",x);
});
```

I'm guessing that the program has no idea what "this" is when I refer to a class, but it should still do something, like perform the interior code on each .big_square, where nothing seems to happen. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remember that ID's can't be just numeric. Either add alpha numeric ID's or only use letters.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen Not true in the HTML5 spec.

Comment: They can be numbers with an html5 doctype, but I am also just using them as generic placeholders for the sake of the question.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyGrist, didn't know that. Still weird though.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are just trying to find the `id` of the value that was clicked inside the click callback.  If so just use the following.

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

**EDIT**

As a couple of people have noted you can also just avoid jQuery altogether here and do the following which is a bit more performant

```
var id = this.id;
```

Comment: As Anthony Grist states in another answer, you can just do this.id, which is a little more performant.

Comment: Thanks, this returns the ID for an input ID, however, if I refer to the set of divs by class, it will still not find the one which I have clicked.

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementById` is used to retrieve the DOM element with the given id; it returns `null` in case there's no matching element.

In order to get the id of the clicked element you could use `$(this).attr("id");`, or the less verbose, and jQuery-exclusive `this.id`.

Comment: Or just `this.id` - access properties directly whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks, this returns the ID for an input ID, however, if I refer to the set of divs by class, it will still not find the one which I have clicked.